# How to solve coupled differential equations numerically?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

I've just started a project, trying to do simulation of electrodynamics using the well-known Maxwell equations:
$$
\nabla \cdot \mathbf E = \rho \\ \; \\
\nabla \cdot \mathbf B = 0 \\ \; \\
\nabla \times \mathbf E = -\frac{\partial \mathbf B}{\partial t} \\ \; \\
\nabla \times \mathbf B = \mathbf J + \frac{\partial \mathbf E}{\partial t} \\ \; \\
$$
Once I setted up the project, I was going to see how could I simulate the equations, but they are coupled. For example:
$$
\nabla \cdot \mathbf E = \frac{\partial E^1}{\partial x_1} + \frac{\partial E^2}{\partial x_2} + \frac{\partial E^3}{\partial x_3} = \rho
$$
This equations depends on $E^1$, $E^2$ and $E^3$, which we have to find with the others equations. It is possible to write individual equations for each field component, to then integrate numerically? Is there any other better method? I'm new to all of this, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There’s a really large world of this. Maybe start in the [Computational Science stack](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com).

Comment: keywords ["Maxwell solvers"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_field_solver)